# Vue-Router in axios interceptor

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-router

I create one project with the vue-cli 3, so I run:

```
>vue create my-app;
>cd my-app
>vue add axios
```

the vue create in my my-app\src\plugins\ the file axios.js with this code:

```
"use strict";

import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from "axios";

// Full config:  https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config
// axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.baseURL || process.env.apiUrl || '';
// axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;
// axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

let config = {
  // baseURL: process.env.baseURL || process.env.apiUrl || ""
  // timeout: 60 * 1000, // Timeout
  // withCredentials: true, // Check cross-site Access-Control
};

const _axios = axios.create(config);

_axios.interceptors.request.use(
  function(config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    return config;
  },
  function(error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

// Add a response interceptor
_axios.interceptors.response.use(
  function(response) {
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  },
  function(error) {
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

Plugin.install = function(Vue, options) {
  Vue.axios = _axios;
  window.axios = _axios;
  Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
    axios: {
      get() {
        return _axios;
      }
    },
    $axios: {
      get() {
        return _axios;
      }
    },
  });
};

Vue.use(Plugin)

export default Plugin;
```

but I need to in response interceptor access the vue-router, I already try to add the import Router from 'vue-router';  and use Roter.push() but when execute the say that push are not a method. I can't use This or Vue.$router too..

how can I fix this? tks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to use router inside axios interceptor or pretty much anywhere outside component's files, we have to import router instance of our application, that is created inside router entry file (by default `router.js`).

Instance should be imported from the same path, as it is done in application's entry file (by default `main.js`):

```
import router from './router'
```

This way all methods can be accessed, as described in [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)

Comment: I did it slightly differently - I had axios configuration setup inside a function which was called by the router config, and passing itself in.